# Flexdashboard can't find input/session

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I have been using Shiny/Flexdashboard for a couple of days and out of nowhere all of my code stopped working and I just get session or input not found errors. I tried re-installing RStudio and R and all the packages, but it didn't work.

When running my code I get something like this:

```
Warning: Error in dropNulls: objeto 'session' não encontrado
Stack trace (innermost first):
    117: dropNulls
    116: updateSelectizeInput
    115: eval
    114: eval
    113: withVisible
    112: withCallingHandlers
    111: handle
    110: timing_fn
    109: evaluate_call
    108: evaluate::evaluate
    107: evaluate
    106: in_dir
    105: block_exec
    104: call_block
    103: process_group.block
    102: process_group
    101: withCallingHandlers
    100: process_file
     99: knitr::knit
     98: <Anonymous>
     97: do.call
     96: contextFunc
     95: .getReactiveEnvironment()$runWith
     94: shiny::maskReactiveContext
     93: <reactive>
     82: doc
     81: shiny::renderUI
     80: func
     79: origRenderFunc
     78: output$__reactivedoc__
      3: <Anonymous>
      2: do.call
      1: rmarkdown::run
Warning: Error in %in%: objeto 'input' não encontrado
Stack trace (innermost first):
    73: %in%
    72: [.data.frame
    71: [ [<text>#13]
    70: <reactive:sliderDatMP> [<text>#13]
    59: sliderDatMP
    58: observerFunc [<text>#36]
     3: <Anonymous>
     2: do.call
     1: rmarkdown::run
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer
```

But it's not just in my code, I can try to run the simple [Old faithul example](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/shiny.html) on the flexdashboard website and the same thing happens.

[Screenshot of what I get running the Old faithul](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oha6G.png)

I have absolutely no idea what happened, it was working just fine the whole week and now nothing works. All help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem than you

Answer (score 1):

Identified as issue with [rmarkdown](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1193). Solution from within R:

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/rmarkdown")
```